# Fastest way to load a page from different domain

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, cross-domain

What I'd like to do is simple :

I want to load asynchronously an .aspx page (let say, www.crossdomain.com/PageToAdd.aspx) into my actual page (let say, www.actualdomain.com/Index.aspx). Both pages (and domains) are under my controls, so I can make any kind of stuff as well.

How can I do it? What I tried :

1. `.load()` from jQuery, but it doesnt works cross-domain;
2. `.ajax()` from jQuery, using JSONP, but seems its so boring serialize the whole PageToAdd.aspx to JSON (in fact, I can't put the whole html pagecode in a single node, because the page size it is too high, and it will be broken);

So, what can I try to do?

Please note! I need to "avoid" iFrame, for some reasons.

Answer (score 1):

you can .load("actualdomain/parseforme.aspx?url=remotedoomain/please.aspx"); I think? Just you need to write a parseforme.aspx in your application which gets the remote file in your domain.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a proxy to put in your domain or use an `iframe`. Since you want to avoid the `iframe` you'll rely on the proxy; then you will have to `.load()` your proxy, which will call the remote URL and give back the HTML of that page.

Note that if the remote page makes some AJAX calls to their own web services, those AJAX call will be blocked for the Same Origin Policy. An `iframe` will be safer and faster to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Since you control both domains, you can add CORS support to one of them. This will allow the contents to be loaded via XMLHttpRequest. You can learn more about configuring CORS here:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/